# distinguish a swipe and click in android (pass event to other view if it is a swipe)

Tags: android, onclick, scrollview, gesture, swipe

hi i have an overlay (a linearlayout) that is on top of another view (scrollview)
now i want the user to still be able to scroll up and down via the scrollview, but whenever they click, the overlay should intercept the click event and do something else.  if it is a swipe, or actually anything other than click, the overlay should ignore and pass the event to the views behind it.

i tried to bind onClick to the overlay, but it is not able to tell a tap/click and a swipe, i.e. a swipe triggers the onClick of the overlay, a tap/click als triggers the same onClick event
in other words, user cannot scroll down...
can anyone help?

1. is there a way i can pass the event to others, i.e. in this case scrollview so it can scroll down?